# Can you keep original Date Created and Date Modified when uploading photo using multer?

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm uploading a photo using this code:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, '/home/vk/uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('avatar');


app.post('/profile', async (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            var FileName = req.file.filename;
            res.status(200).send(FileName);
        }
    })
});
```

It works well. But I want to keep the original date created and date modified attributes of the photo (Date created at least). Right now, suppose if the photo has `Date Created: ‎31 ‎January ‎2020, ‏‎00:00:00`, multer upload replaces it with current time and date. Same for Modified.

Is there any way to do this with multer or NodeJS? Or it simply doesn't make any sense hence it's not possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to keep the original date created and date modified
> attributes of the photo (Date created at least).

When you ask user the new image you will replace the image i.e deleting the existing image and uploading a new one. If you want to keep all the images uploaded by user then you don't need to check modify date as they will be no modification in photos.

Instead of keeping track of `originalDate` and `modifiedDate` in multer(not available in API) you can keep it in DB for that field.

Multer API only provides these fields:

```
Key              Description                                   Note
fieldname        Field name specified in the form    
originalname     Name of the file on the user’s computer     
encoding         Encoding type of the file   
mimetype         Mime type of the file   
size             Size of the file in bytes   
destination      The folder to which the file has been saved    DiskStorage
filename         The name of the file within the destination    DiskStorage
path             The full path to the uploaded file             DiskStorage
buffer           A Buffer of the entire file                    MemoryStorage
```

You can check [here](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html) for more details.